# Cuál tiempo verbal (subjuntivo vs condicional vs preterito indefenido) se puede usar y cuándo para pedir algo cortésmente y cuáles son las diferencias

Tags: uso-de-palabras, tiempos-verbales

Observé varios tiempos verbales que se pueden usar para pedir algo cortésmente a alguien:

*Yo **quisiera** saber...*

*Me **gustaría** saber...*

***Quería** dos tomates y un melón...*

¿Cómo decidir cuál de estos tiempos usar? ¿De qué depende esto?

P.S. Por adelantado agradezco que corrijan errores en mi pregunta en caso de que los haya.

Comment: Dos tomates y un melón, si a vuestra merced le complace.

Comment: @Alex Perhaps the examples you give = the difference in courtesy between: I wish (to know); I would like (to know); I wanted (two tomatoes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los dos primeros son un poco más corteses, pero los tres suenan bien para realizar pedidos:

- Yo quisiera saber...
- Yo querría saber...
- Yo quería saber...
- Me gustaría saber... (con el verbo "gustar", solo funciona el potencial)
- Quisiera dos tomates y un melón...
- Querría dos tomates y un melón...
- Quería dos tomates y un melón...